# Adding an autoplaying mode in my javascript slider

Tags: javascript, slider, slideshow, settimeout, autoplay

I need to add an autoplaying mode and set timeout to my javascript slider (no jQuery is used)

Here's the script:

```
$('.slide_nav span').click(function () {
        $('.slide_nav .slide_nav_a').removeClass('slide_nav_a');
        $(this).addClass('slide_nav_a');
        var thisEl = $('.slide_nav span').index(this);
        thisEl = thisEl * -100;
        thisEl+='%';
        $('.slide:first').css('margin-left',thisEl);
     });
```

I really don't know what should I need to add. I've tried a lot from search result by keywords but it doesn't help.

Thanks

Comment: No jQuery is used? `$` seems to indicate the presence of jQuery in your code sample.

Comment: I thought this way, but if you're sure -that's it.

Comment: What should I add if it's jQuery?